# Can we assign pre determined RGB HEX color codes to slices of a chart in MS-Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, colors

I have been provided with a set of 9 RGB HEX color code that I will have to use for each slice of a pie chart in MS-Excel.

[image: RGB HEX color code]

I will have to fill up this chart with each of these codes (in no particular order).

[image: Pie Chart]

Now in MS-Excel we can individually select one slice in the chart and change the color based on the HEX codes that I have been provided.

Instead of individually selecting a slice and changing the color one at a time, is it possible to change the colors of all the 9 slices in the chart as per the above 9 HEX color codes?

Comment: Please don't. Use a bar chart and a single colour (unless you need to call attention to one specific bar in which case make that bolder eg orange vs yellow or dark blue vs mid blue.) Almost no-one has a working memory that will handle 9 arbitrary colours which means everyone will spend more time looking from the chart to the legend and back than actually thinking about the data. A bar chart with direct labels requires none of this effort and lets pre-attentive processing get to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the Microsoft article
[Save a custom chart as a template](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/save-a-custom-chart-as-a-template-259a5f9d-a9ec-4b3f-94b6-9f5e55187f2a).
After reading it, do the following:

- Create a dummy chart with 9 series
- Assign your colors to the chart
- Right-click the chart and select "Save as Template"
- Give the template a name and Save

To apply the template to a new chart:

- Right-click and select "Change Chart Type"
- Click "Templates" folder
- Select your template.